# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members') discord js

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

In my bot, I constantly get an error that it does not see participants

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: new Discord.Intents(32767)
})
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('909512069999628349'); 

client.on('ready', () =>   
{
    guild.members.fetch()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bot is not being logged into Discord before the guild is attempted to be fetched. It's simple. Just move the `const guild` inside the Ready event, or use a hack similar to this:

```js
let guild;
client.on('ready', () => {
  guild = client.guilds.cache.get('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `members?.fetch()`, probably your object might be undefined so do this instead